# nodejs executin a binary from different folder of a nodejs app

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a nodejs application executing from folder A a binary X also in folder A (using child process `exec`). Binary X produce an output file O in folder A, so always from where is called.

I need instead the nodejs app to to execute the binary X in an arbitrational folder and produce an output O in a different folder from where the nodejs application A is being execute.

So basically I need to execute the binary as would be in different folder.

I would like to know if it is possible to do this in nodejs and how to do it?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, You would like `Binary X` to output a file `O` in a given directory? Correct me if I'm wrong, please.

Firstly, I would look into checking if the binary has an option to specify where to output the file. If not, perhaps the best way to solve this is by setting the current working directory.

I would do the following:

```js
import {spawn} from 'child_process';
import * as path from 'path';
import * as os from 'os';

const proc = spawn('./binary.exe', [<Array of parameters to binary>], {
  cwd: `${path.join(os.homedir, filename)}.o`
});

proc.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);
```

[The Official Nodejs Docs](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options)

The `cwd` property is the active ingredient here. It specifies where the binary should be run from. The `spawn` function simply executes executables and binaries in much the same way a terminal does.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks you understand correctly, the binary as NO option to output the file to a specific directory

Comment: Cool. Let me know how it goes and don't forget to accept the answer if it worked. Thanks.